# use bootstrap required validation for asp.net instead of RequiredFieldvalidator

Tags: asp.net, bootstrap-4

I have a form where users can sign in and another form on the same page where the user can sign up.

I want to apply required="required" for some controls where empty is not allowed. But on click for sign up button, it is first referring to the textbox of sign-in control and giving error.

Both sign in and sign up are located separately inside the panel. I want to remove asp: RequiredFieldValidator here and replace them by "required". Or Is there any way I can always display the * next to the textbox.

```html
 <div style="float: right; margin-right: 20px; font-size: 15px; margin-top: 5px; margin-bottom: 5px;">
                <asp:Panel ID="pnlLogin" runat="server" DefaultButton="btnLogin" Style="margin-left: 50px;">
                    <div style="float: left; margin-top: 15px;">
                        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtLogin" ValidationGroup="Signin" class="form-control"
                            PlaceHolder="Partner Email"></asp:TextBox>
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="reqtxtLogin" ValidationGroup="Signin" runat="server"
                            SetFocusOnError="True" ControlToValidate="txtLogin" ForeColor="Black" ErrorMessage="E-mail is required."
                            Display="Dynamic" ToolTip="E-mail is required.">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                        <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="regtxtLogin" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Invalid email."
                            Display="Dynamic" SetFocusOnError="True" ControlToValidate="txtLogin" ValidationExpression="^([\w\.\-]+)@([\w\-]+)((\.(\w){2,3})+)$"
                            ForeColor="Black" ValidationGroup="Signin" />
                    </div>
                    <div style="float: left; margin-left: 20px; margin-top: 15px;">
                        <asp:TextBox runat="server" TextMode="Password" ID="txtLoginpassword" ValidationGroup="Signin"
                            class="form-control" PlaceHolder="Password"></asp:TextBox>
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="reqtxtLoginpassword" runat="server" SetFocusOnError="True"
                            ControlToValidate="txtLoginpassword" Display="Dynamic" ForeColor="Black" ErrorMessage="Password is required."
                            ToolTip="Password is required." ValidationGroup="Signin">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                    </div>
                    <div style="margin-left: 20px; float: left; margin-top: 15px;">
                        <asp:Button ID="btnLogin" runat="server" Text="Log In" ValidationGroup="Signin" OnClick="btnLogin_Click"
                            class="form-control" />
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblLoginError" Style="float: left;" runat="server" ForeColor="Black"
                            Text="Email Id or password is not correct" Visible="false"></asp:Label>
                    </div>
                </asp:Panel>
            </div>
```

Comment: "I want to remove asp:RequiredFieldValidator"...bear in mind that this will remove any server-side validation, so if a malicious user removes the client-side bootstrap/HTML5 validation, then you will have no way to validate your data (unless you add some custom server-side validation back in).

Comment: Anyway you didn't show the "sign up" part of the code, but it sounds like maybe you have an issue with ValidationGroups. Make sure you use a separate validation group for each set of controls and buttons, and you should have no problems. That's probably a better solution than removing some of the validation controls.